# How to copy with cp to include hidden files and hidden directories and their contents?

Tags: unix, cp, recursive

How can I make `cp -r` copy *absolutely all* of the files and directories in a directory

Requirements:

- Include hidden files and hidden directories.
- Be one single command with an flag to include the above.
- Not need to rely on pattern matching at all.

My ugly, but working, hack is:

```
cp -r /etc/skel/* /home/user
cp -r /etc/skel/.[^.]* /home/user
```

How can I do this all in one command without the pattern matching?
What flag do I need to use?

Comment: More answers here, though they do not look as good;
http://serverfault.com/questions/3154/recursively-copying-hidden-files-linux/

Comment: Please, Eleven81, consider changing the accepted answer to that given by @bruno pereira, because it avoids creating a new folder. If not, let this comment be a warning to new readers to check also the other (most voted) answer. Tx.

Comment: How about running `shopt -u dotglob` to include hidden files then run `cp -rfv /etc/skel /home/user` which will also show you progress in case you are copying a big directory.

Answer (score 411, accepted):

Don't specify the files:

> `cp -r /etc/skel /home/user`

(Note that `/home/user` must not exist already, or else it will create `/home/user/skel`.)

Comment: Is it possible to use something similar if `/home/user/skel` *does* exist?

Comment: @bradley.ayers I think one could copy into a temporary subdirectory  then move them to the upper level (since moving in the same drive is fast). Less than ideal, but shorter than other solutions to me.

Comment: @bradley.ayers Bruno's answer below addresses your question

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. It did not copy hidden files. I'm using CentOS release 6.5. @Bruno's solution did the trick.

Comment: Under ubuntu/debian this places the directory 'skel' inside target directory and not the recursed files inside skel. Use `-T` (no target) per below for proper use. (`-rT` for recursive)

Comment: This does not copy hidden (dot) files like '.profile' or '.bashrc'

Comment: If `/home/user` does exist, then this will copy the contents of `/etc/skel` without making `/home/user/skel`: `find /etc/skel -type f -exec cp {} /home/user \;`

Comment: **Beware** that this does not preserve file-attributes by default. So make sure to add your mix of timestamps/xattr/etc. via the -p/--preserve flag! (compare man page)

Comment: Answering a 7.5 year old question, you can run `cp -r /etc/skel/. /home/user` to avoid creating the subdirectory (note the `/.` following etc/skel).

Answer (score 756):

Lets say you created the new folder (or are going to create one) and want to copy the files to it after the folder is created

```
mkdir /home/<new_user>
cp -r /etc/skel/. /home/<new_user>
```

This will copy all files/folder recursively from `/etc/skel` in to the already existing folder created on the first line.

Comment: If I didn't get it wrong, this didn't copy hidden/dot files.

Comment: Works well for me.  Note that the '.' is critical to it working.

Comment: It works, but, why ? Can't find a reference to this in the manual.

Comment: This is the best answer for what I needed and probably many others.

Comment: I think it works because normally, this would create a new folder with the name of the last folder in the first argument.  However, since that name is `.`, this behavior would require it to create an already-existing directory, so it just skips that step.

Comment: Considered an edit but will rather comment to give more chance for review. I think there should be a third command line saying `chown -R <new_user>:<new_user> /home/<new_user>` to pass ownership of the files to the new user.

Comment: Well, I will disagree, the current answer is the right one for the question. You would need to also edit the title of the question (and the question itself) to match the suggested edit to this answer.

Comment: Well it's never bad if the answer is better than the question. Could be in a separate note. If you don't do that, you'll end up with a non-working which may be surprising because the system tools that copy the skeleton automatically do make sure the ownership is correct. I'd even say that this is a solution to the question but it *creates* a new problem on the way that it doesn't solve.

Comment: Note that the answers are not only for the OP but also for anyone who finds the page via web search.

Comment: The reason that this works is that it's equivalent to `cp -r /etc/skel /home/<new_user>`.  The dot `.` is a shell equivalent name for "_This directory_", just as the double-dot `..` means "_Go up one directory_" relative to the given path.  It's a relative path specifier.  Try this: `ls -d /etc/skel/.`  You should see that bash `eval`s this to: `/etc/skel/.`  If you were to try `ls -l /home/<myuser>/.`, you would see files in `/home/<myuser>`

Comment: @BrunoPereira: Thanks! Your solution worked for me but i'm curious to know why using '.' (dot) copies the hidden file.

Comment: Hy @Technext, the explanation from TrinitronX seems to be on the spot: could not explain it better myself.

Comment: Hmmm...i did read his comment but was then confused why * doesn't work. Seems * matches everything but dot (.) files.

Comment: @Technext The default globbing in bash does not include filenames starting with a `.`, to change that you need to use the `shopt -s dotglob` command before to be able to include those files. So with `*`, by default, you are asking to copy all files recursively from this directory that can be expanded using `*` (which does not include hidden files by default). While on the other end with `.` you are using cp to recursively copy everything from "this directory".

Comment: @BrunoPereira: Thanks a lot for the explanation! :) Now it's all clear. :)

Comment: This should be an accepted answer

Comment: @JulienPalard [We finally have an answer to that!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409227/67771)

Comment: Note that you should use `cp -R` because `cp -r` is not well-defined by POSIX (and has a slightly different behaviour on macOS). See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cp.html and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18712/difference-between-cp-r-and-cp-r-copy-command

Comment: Great answer. I've been stumped by this many times. So, to copy from some dir into the current dir, the command is as follows. Don't be confused by the two dots: `cp -r path/to/from_dir/. .`

Answer (score 275):

The correct means of doing this is to use the `-T (--no-target-directory)` option, and recursively copy the folders (without trailing slashes, asterisks, etc.), i.e.:

```
cp -rT /etc/skel /home/user
```

This will copy the contents of `/etc/skel` to `/home/user` (including hidden files), creating the folder `/home/user` if it does not exist; however the `-T` option prevents the contents of `/etc/skel` from being copied to a new folder `/home/user/skel` should the folder `/home/user` exist.

Comment: Correct answer. +1

Comment: this was indeed exactly the right answer

Comment: this is the BEST answer of the bunch; its the only one that solves the problem without complicating it

Comment: exactly works to copy as expected

Comment: Love it when you use the correct cmd flag for the one case.

Comment: Not supported on all versions of `cp`, alas, but great when it is there.

Comment: Doesn't work on mac :(

Comment: Related question, is that the appropriate way to have `/etc/skel` files copied to a user? or should it be done via `adduser` or GUI?

Comment: Works even in LibreELEC with ssh ...

Comment: Any tips for achieving this on mac bash and zsh both?

```bash-5.2$ cp
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-aclpsvXx] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-aclpsvXx] source_file ... target_directory```
or
even on bash 3.2 (the current available version in Recovery Mode terminal)

Answer (score 83):

`bash` itself has a good solution, it has a `shell option`, You can `cp`, `mv` and so on.:

```
shopt -s dotglob # for considering dot files (turn on dot files)
```

and

```
shopt -u dotglob # for don't considering dot files (turn off dot files)
```

Above solution is standard of `bash`

**NOTE:**

```
shopt # without argument show status of all shell options
-u # abbrivation of unset 
-s # abbrivation of set
```

Comment: That's usefull when you want to copy just content without creating new directory inside destination. Especially when destination dir is mount point.

Comment: It's `setopt` for zsh, in case anyone else is wondering.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Users shouldn't have to modify their workflows to account for the sins of Unix. Configuring your shell to act how you expect it to act is always a better solution.

Answer (score 36):

Use rsync:

`rsync -rtv source_folder/ destination_folder/`

Comment: Best option for me, although I use --progress to have more feedback on the whole process.

Answer (score 9):

`rsync` is good, but another choice:

```
cp -a src/ dst/
```

From the main help:

```
   -a, --archive
          same as -dR --preserve=all

   -d     same as --no-dereference --preserve=links

   -R, -r, --recursive
          copy directories recursively
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect in terms of the original question asked (include hidden files): both `cp -r` as well as `cp -a` copy hidden files when cp ... src dst or cp ... src/ dst/ is used. It may be that this changed overtime.

Comment: works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

## The simplest way is:

```
cp -r /etc/skel/{.,}* /home/user
```

The expression `{.,}*` includes all files and directories (also starting with a dot).

If you don't want use above expression, then you can use the `cp` property, which is the ability to specify multiple sources for one target folder:

```
cp -r /etc/skel/* /home/user
```

Comment: this would miss files like `..anything` or `...anything` etc. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31438355/2351568 contains the correct regex for this problem. **||** but anyway using `shopt -s dotglob` is still the better solution!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy unfortunately, I do not understand why you wrote your attention. After all, my solution takes into account the cases you write about. Regards

Comment: sorry wrong text! - the problem with your answer is, that it will also consider `.` and `..` (which is equivalent to the current and its containing folder). **||** but still the [answer in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31438355/2351568) explains it further and provides a solution.

Comment: This answer is very wrong as it actually recuses UP the file tree!

Answer (score 5):

If your source and target directory have the same name, even if target directory exists, you can simply type:

```
cp -R /etc/skel /home/
```

This will copy the /etc/skel directory into /home/, including hidden files and directories.

Eventually, you can copy the directory and rename it in a single line :

```
cp -R /etc/skel /home/ && mv /home/skel /home/user
```

Comment: Or you could simply use `cp -r /etc/skel /home/user` for renaming `skel` to `user`...

Comment: That's right, only if /home/user does not exist yet.

Answer (score 5):

I came here having Googled for a solution to the same problem, then I realized that it's easy to do with find. The advantage it doesn't depend on the shell, or special utilities that may not be installed.

```
find /etc/skel/ -mindepth 1 -exec cp -r {} /home/username/ \;
```

I tried the trick with trailing slash, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: This also lets you exclude some files/directories with exclusion filters (e.g. `! -name 'dontcopythis'`) which might be handy.

Answer (score 4):

You could use rsync.

```
rsync -aP ./from/dir/ /some/other/directory/
```

You can even copy over ssh

```
rsync -aP ./from/dir/ username@remotehost:/some/other/directory/
```

There are various flags you can use:
    -a, --archive    # archive (-rlptgoD)

```
-r, --recursive
-l, --links      # copy symlinks as links
-p, --perms      # preserve permissions
-t, --times      # preserve times
-g, --group      # preserve group
-o, --owner      # preserve owner
-D               # --devices --specials

--delete         # Delete extra files

You may want to add the -P option to your command.

--partial        # By default, rsync will delete any partially transferred file if the transfer is interrupted. In some circumstances it is more desirable to keep partially transferred files. Using the --partial option tells rsync to keep the partial file which should make a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.

-P               # The -P option is equivalent to --partial --progress.   Its  purpose  is to make it much easier to specify these two options for a long transfer that may be interrupted.
```

[Rsync man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html)

Answer (score 3):

Note that there is a command-line trick (works in, at least, *sh*, *bash*, and *ksh*): Just suffix the *from* directory with a slash. This will pour the contents of the *from* directory into the *to* directory (ironically, I had first learned about this trick when *using* *rsync*).

Example:

```
/tmp$ mkdir test_dir1
/tmp$ cd test_dir1/
/tmp/test_dir1$ touch aa
/tmp/test_dir1$ touch .bb
/tmp/test_dir1$ cd ..
/tmp$ mkdir test_dir2

/tmp$ cp -r test_dir1/* test_dir2
/tmp$ ls -1a test_dir2
.
..
aa

/tmp$ cp -r test_dir1/ test_dir2
/tmp$ ls -1a test_dir2
.
..
.bb
aa
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this problem when I have to **copy all the files** (including `.` files) to a target directory **retaining the permissions** is: (overwrite if already exists)

```
yes | cp -rvp /source/directory /destination/directory/
```

`yes` is for automatically overwriting destination files, 
`r` recursive, 
`v` verbose, 
`p` retain permissions.

Notice that the **source path is not ending with a `/`** (so all the files/directory and . files are copied)

**Destination directory ends with `/`** as we are placing contents of the source folder to destination as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the content of a folder /source to another existing folder /dest, **including hidden files**, with the command:

```
$ cp -a /source/. /dest/
```

*The -a option is an improved recursive option, that preserve all file attributes, and also preserve symlinks.*

*The . at end of the source path is a specific cp syntax that allowes to copy all files and folders, including hidden ones.*

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Comment: Agree with @Toto - Your answer is the same as that of [@BrunoPereira's answer](https://superuser.com/a/367303/1210833) which was posted 11 years ago and already has nearly 700 upvotes.  I know there are a lot of answers here to read through before posting yours, but please do it.  There's just no sense in adding *yet answer* to the long list (currently 20) unless you truly have something new and useful to add.  It just makes it even more difficult for the *next* user to find the existing answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
cp -r /etc/skel/. /home/user/
```

The slash (`/`) after "user" does make a difference.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that cp does not always copy hidden files and if you would like an command that seems to work across all linux/unix dialects you should try using:

```
cd /etc/skel
find | cpio -pdumv /home/user
```

Answer (score -2):

To copy files, directories and hidden files from a directory to existing/new directory:

```
cp -a /etc/skel /home/user
```

Copy to current directory:

```
cp -a /etc/skel/. .
```

Answer (score -2):

ignore error

```
cp -r asdf/* qwer/
cp -r asdf/.[^.]* qwer/ 2>/dev/null | true
```

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Answer (score -3):

As of at least K3b 2.0.3, there is a question box that pops up when the directory is added to the project, that ask if you want to include hidden files ... there is also a question that pops up to ask about including links.
Nice stuff!

Comment: "a question box that pops up" — for a shell (CLI) command?